# Displaying Dynamic Variable Value

Tags: php, webforms, variable-variables

I have a form that will ultimately create a pipe delimited text file. The form contains multiple rows each row has multiple drop down fields named `1_cat[]`, `2_cat[]`, `3_cat[]` etc.

In the form submission script I have:

```
if ($submit) {
   foreach($_POST['videofile'] as $row=>$item)
   {
      $videofile = $_POST['videofile'][$row];
      $videotype = $_POST['videotype'][$row];

      for($i=0; $i<=$drop_fields; $i=$i+1) {
         $val = $i."_cat[".$row."]"; // HERE'S WHERE I'M HAVING DIFFICULTY
         $cat = $cat.$val.",";
      }
      print "$videofile|$videotype|$cat";
      $cat = "";
   }
}
```

The code below outputs `1_cat[0],2_cat[0],3_cat[0]`, `1_cat[1],2_cat[1],3_cat[1]` etc. -- so it displays the names, but not values of those variables as I would like it to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things in this code snippet that should be corrected:

A [valid variable name](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. `1_cat` is not a valid variable name. If you wish to use your form fields as variable names, you will need to change the field names in your form.

`videofile` needs a `$`: `$videofile`

The `for` loop counter can be incremented like this: `$i++`. This is cleaner and more standard than `$i=$i+1`.

The line `$cat = $cat.$val.",";` uses `$cat` before it is initialized. You should provide an initial value for `$cat` before the start of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Generally if `$val` holds the *name* of the variable you want to reference, `$$val` will give you the *value* of that variable. In your case, since you are also indexing into an array, it is slightly more complicated to write.

You need to change

```
$val = $i."_cat[".$row."]"; // HERE'S WHERE I'M HAVING DIFFICULTY
$cat = $cat.$val.",";
```

to

```
$val = $i."_cat";
$cat = $cat.${$val}[$row].",";
```

Refer to the PHP documentation section on [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) for all the details.

Also, variable names cannot start with numbers, so you will need to tweak the naming scheme a bit.

**Update:** Fixed the code (indexing into an array is slightly more complex to write), added variable name note.

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/cJj5C)**.

Comment: Since `1_cat` is an array, you need to do this: `$arr = $i.'_cat'; $val = $$arr;  $cat = $cat.$val[$row].",";`.  Also, BTW, `1_cat` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: @Rocket: I hadn't tested it, but it should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your field names in the HTML Page are actually called stuff like `<select name="1_cat[0]">` and the like?

You'd access those, using your loops, like this:

```
$_POST[$i . '_' . 'cat'][0] ... or .... $_POST["{$i}_cat"][0]
$_POST[$i . '_' . 'cat'][1] ... or .... $_POST["{$i}_cat"][1]
$_POST[$i . '_' . 'cat'][2] ... or .... $_POST["{$i}_cat"][2]
etc...
```

Unless you've got register_globals turned on (you don't, right? please tell me you don't...), there will NEVER bee a PHP variable named `$1_cat[0]` to begin with.

Comment: Also, PHP variables cannot start with a number, so `$1_cat` is invalid.